# MySQL select rows only where specific column value has changed

Tags: mysql

I hope someone can help me out with some MySQL logic.

I am looking after a MySQL database that contains an audit trail for entries to our production databases.  This audit log triggers an action for each INSERT, UPDATE or delete.

An example of the format of the table I am looking at is shown below:

| AudID | AudAction | AudTimestamp | Group | Expires | Meta | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | GRP_1 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | 11111 | User_1 |
| 1002 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:01:00 | GRP_2 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | 11111 | User_2 |
| 1003 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:02:00 | GRP_3 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | 11111 | User_1 |
| 1004 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:03:00 | GRP_4 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | 11111 | User_1 |
| 1005 | UPDATE | 2023-01-01 00:04:00 | GRP_1 | 2023-01-29 00:00:00 | 11111 | User_5 |
| 1006 | UPDATE | 2023-01-01 00:05:00 | GRP_1 | 2023-01-29 00:00:00 | 22222 | User_1 |
| 1007 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:06:00 | GRP_5 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | 11111 | User_5 |
| 1008 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:07:00 | GRP_6 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | 11111 | User_1 |
| 1009 | UPDATE | 2023-01-01 00:08:00 | GRP_4 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 22222 | User_3 |
| 1010 | UPDATE | 2023-01-01 00:09:00 | GRP_4 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | 22222 | User_1 |
| 1011 | UPDATE | 2023-01-01 00:10:00 | GRP_3 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 33333 | User_4 |
| 1012 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:11:00 | GRP_7 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 11111 | User_1 |
| 1013 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:12:00 | GRP_8 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 11111 | User_6 |
| 1014 | UPDATE | 2023-01-01 00:13:00 | GRP_1 | 2023-01-31 00:00:00 | 22222 | User_1 |
| 1015 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:14:00 | GRP_9 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 11111 | User_7 |

I have been asked to generate a report listing of all changes to the **Expires** field grouped by the **Group** field.  I do not want to include rows that update other fields (of which there are many), just changes to the **Expires** field when compared to the previous row for that group.

So for each time the Expires field is created or updates, I would like a row to be shown, but no new entries if another field in the row is changed.

I have no idea how to go about creating the SQL for this type of approach.

This is the output I am looking for from the query.

| AudID | AudAction | AudTimestamp | Group | Expires | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | GRP_1 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | User_1 |
| 1005 | UPDATE | 2023-01-01 00:04:00 | GRP_1 | 2023-01-29 00:00:00 | User_5 |
| 1014 | UPDATE | 2023-01-01 00:13:00 | GRP_1 | 2023-01-31 00:00:00 | User_1 |
| 1002 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:01:00 | GRP_2 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | User_2 |
| 1003 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:02:00 | GRP_3 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | User_1 |
| 1004 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:03:00 | GRP_4 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | User_1 |
| 1010 | UPDATE | 2023-01-01 00:09:00 | GRP_4 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | User_1 |
| 1007 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:06:00 | GRP_5 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | User_5 |
| 1008 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:07:00 | GRP_6 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | User_1 |
| 1012 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:11:00 | GRP_7 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | User_1 |
| 1013 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:12:00 | GRP_8 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | User_6 |
| 1015 | INSERT | 2023-01-01 00:14:00 | GRP_9 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | User_7 |

I really hope the above makes sense and hope someone is able to help with the code for this.

Thank you for reading and any help you may be able to provide!

Comment: ' hope someone is able to help with the code for this.' - Unlikely , suggest you research lag function , try something and if struggling post code attempt

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.